# Why doesn't initWithRootViewController retain the viewController Class that is passed into it?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom viewController called SourceListViewController, and I'm adding it into a UINavigationController, the view of which is then added to the window of the iphone App.  After passing the SourceListViewController to UINavigationController, I release the sourceListViewController.

```
SourceListViewController *sourceListVC = [[SourceListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SourceListViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sourceListVC] autorelease];
[sourceListVC release];
```

When I do this, the app would crash after the view is loaded onto the phone.  When I commented out the last line, the app work fine.  Isn't initWithRootViewController supposed to retain the copy of sourceListVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are autoreleasing navigationController. So if navigationController gets autoreleased (which will probably happen in the next runloop) then so will sourceListVC.

Comment: That does not mean the sourceListVC is retained. Is it like that, when you release the NavigationController, all its ViewController are aslo released and the NVC does not retain the root view controller?